# Encode the Mode as a color in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, statistics

I've got a sensor that I'm collecting data for.  Basically, whether it's on or off depends on the distance it is from what it's designed to sense.  So, I've got this little rig on wheels that I'm using to move the sensor towards the material, and then pulling it away...Then pushing it back and pulling it away again.  Imagine the motion you would make when vacuuming.

So, anyway, When I'm far away, the sensor is off...When I'm really close, the sensor is on.  No issues there.
What I'm interested in is that grey-zone, sweet-spot, butter-zone, whatever you want to call it where sometimes it turns on and maybe on the next pass, it turns on 5mm closer.

I'd like to encode that somehow in this graph of the data that I'm plotting with MatplotLib.  My thought was to heat map the transitions based on the frequency they occur in the data?
[image]

As you can see, it's pretty boring and uninteresting.  I'd like to make it look prettier and fancier by incorporating some other mechanism for conveying the variance of the transitions.  At this point I might have transitioned from high to low and low to high at distance 15 1,000 times, and all the other transitions could have happened once...there's no way to tell.

How can I add that kind of mapping to this kind of data?

And here's the python script...pretty simple stuff:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('/home/dale/test1.txt', delimiter=',', skip_header=10, names=['x','y'])

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title("Distance vs Level")
ax1.set_xlabel('Distance')
ax1.set_ylabel('Logic Level')

ax1.step(data['x'],data['y'], c='r', label='the data')

leg = ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you first have to figure out WHAT you want to achieve and WHY. I don't think that these questions are appropriate for stackoverflow. To "somehow make the graph look fancier" is probably too broad. Once you know how your graph should look like, there will probably be a lot of answers about how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Thomas' comment. The graph has several issues that are immediately apparent from the data.

1) Your distance measures are discrete, whereas you are plotting a continuous line. The graph should not hide that.

2) As the data is continuous, the line ends up being on top of itself a lot. That hides the true frequencies.

Instead of your suggested heatmap, I think that you just need a barplot:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# grab data
df = pd.read_csv('sensor_data.csv')
position = df.Counter
status = df.Value

# determine fraction on;
# I will use bincount for this, which only accepts positive arguments
min_pos = position.min()
position -= min_pos

# determine fraction on
counts_on = np.bincount(position[status==1], minlength=position.max()+1)
counts_all = np.bincount(position, minlength=position.max()+1)
fraction_on = counts_on.astype(float) / counts_all

# plot
x = np.arange(min_pos, position.max()+1+min_pos)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.bar(x-0.5, fraction_on, width=1., facecolor='gray', edgecolor=None)
ax.set_xlabel('Distance')
ax.set_ylabel(r'Logic Level $\frac{ON}{ON + OFF}$')
```

Comment: Hooo-whee!  That's pretty decent my man!  Do you think you could add a best fit line in there?  To get a single line that curves real nice and smooth down the middle of the decline?

Comment: What kind of line do you want to fit? Probably a sigmoidal, if you ask me. You should open a new question if you have difficulties figuring out how to fit lines.